# Porous 3D solid

Tags: rendering, mesh

I need to create a porous structure in Blender (like honeycomb, archimedian, lines, in image). Textures don't work so well. Any help?

[image: Solidify porous structure]

Comment: Have you explored the (included) Mesh:Tissue add-on yet? At first sight, It seems well-suited to this kind of problem.

Comment: Why are textures not working "so well"? What results are you getting and using what settings? What are you expecting to get? Are this images illustrating your goal? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

There are many types of porous structure, but simple ones can be created using the Array Modifier. Create a cube, cylinder, or other object. Then, in edit mode (Tab), delete its top & bottom faces:
[image]
[image]
Then use a solidify modifier on it to thicken the faces:
[image]
Adjust the "thickness" value until it looks good to you:
[image]
(I put a flat surface with walls underneath my example to make it look more like your provided image)
Then use an array modifier to make copies of it in one direction:
[image]
Adjust the "Count" to change the number of copies it makes:
[image]
The result should look like this:
[image]
Add a *second* array modifier to spread it out over the other axis, by adjusting the relative offset (to get the "honeycomb" effect you need to adjust both of the numbers until it looks correct):
[image]
[image]
Once you have the modifiers set up to your liking, press "Apply" on each modifier to finalise the changes, and you're done!
[image]